# What is the regular expression to validate a comma delimited list but ending with '&' and a word

Tags: php, regex

I'm able to extract till **11.20** but after that the comma stops and the regex I wrote fails. How can I write this expression? I'm using `preg_match_all` function.

input string:

```
8, 8.40, 9.20, 10, 10.40, 11.20, 12 & 12.40 latenight
```

output needed:

```
Array
    (

        [0] =>  8,
        [1] =>  8.40,
        [2] =>  9.20,
        [3] =>  10,
        [4] =>  10.40,
        [5] =>  11.20,
        [6] =>  12,
        [7] =>  12.40,
    )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$string = '8, 8.40, 9.20, 10, 10.40, 11.20, 12 & 12.40 latenight';
$string = str_replace('&', ',', $string);
$string = str_replace(' ', ',', $string);

$parts  = preg_split('/,+/', $string);

print_r($parts);
```

prints

```
Array
(
    [0] => 8
    [1] => 8.40
    [2] => 9.20
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 10.40
    [5] => 11.20
    [6] => 12
    [7] => 12.40
    [8] => latenight
)
```

Close enough?

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to match the comma or ampersand is there? Why not just match what you are looking for?

```
var str = "8, 8.40, 9.20, 10, 10.40, 11.20, 12 & 12.40 latenight";

var res = str.match( /\d+(\.\d{2})?|\w+$/g );

console.log( res ); //["8", "8.40", "9.20", "10", "10.40", "11.20", "12", "12.40", "latenight"]

//RegExp parts

\d+      - 1 or more digits 
(        - start optional group
  \.     - a literal decimal point
  \d{2}  - exactly 2 digits
)?       - end optional group
|        - or
\w+$     - a word at the end of the string
```

If you don't want the word at the end then leave the last clause out.

```
var str = "8, 8.40, 9.20, 10, 10.40, 11.20, 12 & 12.40 latenight";

var res = str.match( /\d+(\.\d{2})?/g );

console.log( res ); //["8", "8.40", "9.20", "10", "10.40", "11.20", "12", "12.40"]
```

Comment: This answer is good, however, the 'latenight' should not end up in the array, as seen in the question.

Comment: @Qqwy: Funnily enough my first attempt at this answer didn't match the word at the end - I've added the original version

Comment: You regex is perfect but i have to give the other right due the fact its a php tagged question. Thank you so very much

Answer (score 0):

This expression,

```
[0-9]*(?:\.?[0-9]+)?(?=\s*&|\s*,)
```

might have worked too.

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/F3qTBI/1/)

```
$re = '/[0-9]*(?:\.?[0-9]+)?(?=\s*&|\s*,)/s';
$str = '8, 8.40, 9.20, 10, 10.40, 11.20, 12 & 12.40 latenight';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

var_dump($matches);
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/F3qTBI/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/F3qTBI/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---